# discount to vs discount off vs discount off of vs discount from

Tags: prepositions

> To get the full A app company experience, we recommend you upgrade to
>   our paid version (at a substantial discount **TO** list price).

I found that sentence on a website of an app company and the preposition 'to' is confusing to me. I guess the whole sentence means if the original price is 10 dollars, users can get a huge discount like 30%, 50% or 80%. My question is can I change the preposition having the same meaning as follows?

> a. at a substantial discount **TO** list price
>   b. at a substantial discount **FROM** list price
>   c. at a substantial discount **OFF** list price
>   d. at a substantial discount **OFF OF** list price

Are the four sentences grammatically correct and interchangeable? I am also wondering which one is frequently used most.

Comment: Definitely not "dicount".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard expression appears to be *discount on* (see https://www.writing-skills.com/discount-on-discount-off . *To* could be read as meaning *compared to*.
 *Off of* is definitely nonstandard English.